# scrolltofixed bottom with angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins

I am using [angular-scrolltofixed](https://github.com/xavierdutreilh/angular-scrolltofixed) plugin
and it works great.

The problem starts when I try to put a limit options for the bottom bar

```
 $('.footer').scrollToFixed( { bottom: 0, limit: $('.footer').offset().top } );
```

The 'limit' variable is being calculated before all the page is being fully rendered (ng-repeat etc) and as a result the limit attribute is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, The script loads after entire document loads

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
     <!--
         write  all the code her
     -->
        <script>
         //Add your angualar js script here 
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```